# How to check which components are compiled by which server when using distcc

Tags: makefile, distcc

I've got a distccd daemon running on two servers.
One (call it A, .12) serves as the master, while the other (call it B, .11) serves as a slave:

```
Settings on A:
vim ~/.distcc/hosts
    # contents of ~/.distcc/hosts
    localhost
    192.168.1.11,cpp,lzo

Settings on B:
distccd --daemon --allow 192.168.1.12 --log-file /home/nhlee/distcc.log
"ps aux | grep distcc" to check that it's running
```

Then I build something with:

```
pump make -j xxx
```

And it tells me that:

```
__________Using distcc-pump from /usr/bin
__________Using 2 distcc servers, of which only 1 support(s) pump mode
...
__________Shutting down distcc-pump include server
```

However, the time spent is nearly the same. I'm not sure if there is way to check which components were compiled by which host.

I turned on the monitor with:

```
 distccmon-text 1
```

I tried this on both machines, and both show me empty lines only.

I looked in `/var/look/messages`, but there is nothing related to distcc.

I checked in the log file, which is also empty.

How can I see how my files are being
compiled?

### #

So I checked with top on both machines, and it turns out that all files were compiled on the master's local (A). I'm not sure why there isn't any error, though.

I also tried removing 'localhost' from ~/.distcc/hosts, but the results are still the same.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I tried a few things and solved the problem. And I ran into some new issues that I'd like to share as well.

1. First, I did

   ```
   export CC=/usr/bin/distcc
   export CXX=/usr/bin/distcc
   ```

   to let CMake know that I wanted to use distcc instead of gcc/g++.

   > > This was the main problem. After I did this things were showing up in the monitor.
2. I had two versions of gcc/g++ installed on my machine, an older version under `/usr/bin/` that did not support C++11, and a newer one that did.
   Though my LD_LIBRARY_PATH had the new one's path in the front, somehow distcc wasn't finding the older one first. Thus I ran into some compile errors saying that -std=c++11 wasn't recognized.

   ```
   ## The following solved this issue:
   sudo yum remove /usr/bin/g++
   sudo yum remove /usr/bin/gcc
   ```
3. There were linking errors when I used distcc, but not when I used g++ directly:

   ```
   # Add a simple one-line script (mine was called /usr/bin/distg++)
   distcc g++ "$@"
   ```

   Then add "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=distg++" to your CMake command:

   ```
   cmake ... -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=distg++
   ```